# How to get beans defined in main-servlet.xml from controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller

I understand beans in my main-servlet.xml is in child context. And based on research I know I can get root ApplicationContext within my GreetingController through WebApplicationContextUtils. Which I'll get null because i didn't define such a root context in web.xml.

Now my question is how can i get child context and do something like childContext.getBean("forfun") without @AutoWired annotation,I think I've tested it and it works;

Thanks in advance for your reading and info.

**Edit: AutoWire the ApplicationContext or implement ApplicationContextAware will help you get both the child and root ApplicationContext.**

**Edit2:I found another way to get the context created by defaultdispacher, the context is actually stored in servletcontext attributes with name org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.(servletName) 
supposed your default servlet is `main`, you can get the context craete by defaultdispacher[main-servlet.xml] with the following code.


`ApplicationContext context1=(WebApplicationContext) request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.main")`**

But still don't understand why in the WebApplicationContextUtils method we can't access child context.

web.xml file

```
<webapp>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/main-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/main/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

main-servlet.xml

```
<beans>
<bean name ="/testing/*" class="springmvc.GreetingController"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
p:prefix="/WEB-INF/Jsp/"
p:suffix=".jsp"/>
<bean id="forfun" class="springmvc.Foo"></bean>
</beans>
```

GreetingController.java

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@AutoWired
Foo forfun;//this works even if forfun is defined in main-servlet.xml

@RequestMapping("/testing")
public String testing(HttpServletRequest request){
    ApplicationContext context = 
                WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        Foo f=(Foo) context.getBean("forfun");//supposed to work if i have it defined in root context
    /*
    I would something like this
    ChildContext child = Utils.getChildContext(request);
    Foo f=(Foo) child.getBean("forfun");
    */
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to get it through the `WebApplicationContext`?

Comment: Not for practical reason, just try to see if there's a way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main-servlet.xml` you've declared above is loaded by your `DispatcherServlet`.

You can inject the corresponding `WebApplicationContext` with

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;
```

and use it to get any bean defined in that context or a parent.

Note that this will work only if the bean you're injecting it into is created within the `WebApplicationContext` created by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Alternatively, as stated in the comments by M. Deinum, there's a `static` utility class called `RequestContextUtils` that provides a [`getWebApplicationContext(ServletRequest)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html#getWebApplicationContext-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-) method for doing the same thing.

Comment: thanks so much for you reply,So this autowired WebApplicationContext should contain all beans from parent context to child context ?

Comment: @Jing The `WebApplicationContext` injected is the one containing the bean it's injected _into_. If that's the one loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` (child), you'll have access to the `WebApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` (parent) only **if it exists**.

Comment: Works ~. Just for curiosity is there any other way to get the context without annotation? and why WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext() is not getting 'child context'?

Comment: @Jing `getRequiredWebApplicationContext` returns the `WebApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` (or throws an exception if it doesn't exist). There is no other _standard_ way to get the one loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: thanks so much really. just found a wired way to get it, and I'm sure it's not standard, and it's not recommended. just for curiosity. :D

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Actually there is, by using the [`RequestContextUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html). That will try to find the context for the servlet first before falling back to the root context.

Comment: @M Sweet. I missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: @Jing Turns out I missed an option. See comments and edited answer.